# Pandas upgrade installation fails

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I run

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

on my Windows 7 computer. I currently run pandas version .12.  It seems to struggle with rolling back this version, as I get the error:

```
  Can't roll back pandas; was not uninstalled

  Cleaning up...

Removing temporary dir c:\users\svenka~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_svenkatesh...

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\svenkatesh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Users\svenkatesh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 241, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
File "C:\Users\svenkatesh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1298, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\svenkatesh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 625, in install
cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
File "C:\Users\svenkatesh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Users\svenkatesh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\svenka~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_svenkatesh\\pandas\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\svenka~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-rnlz93-record\install-record.txt --single-version-    externally-managed failed with error code 1 in     c:\users\svenka~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_svenkatesh\pandas
```

How do I upgrade? Should I just delete my current version (v12) of Pandas and do a clean installation of v15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had issues with pip upgrading as well, so for windows, I usually prefer the binaries provided here:

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
```

The binaries include pandas, numpy, and tons others